# Angular Material Datepicker won't show in the page

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, mat-datepicker

I'm trying to add an Angular Material datepicker to the page. I've been following the [official doc's example](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) like so, but nothing displays in my page.

In the `app.component.html` there is:

```
<section>
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
</section>
```

And in the `app.component.ts`, I have:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  panelOpenState = false;
}
```

And this is my `app.module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you fix this issue? I am facing an exact scenario. Datepicker is not showing on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not imported the `FormsModule` in the `@NgModule`.

Please check the below example and its `main.ts` file. It's working.

[Demo Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-datepicker-example?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

I hope it will help.